# Stanford POS-tagger takes too long in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to POS-tag a collection of documents, and to be precise their title and an abstract. I have stored the collection on a MongoDB instance, from where I access them, and POS-tag them using the latest version of the Stanford POS-tagger. The issue is that, it just takes too long to complete,while my collection has about 1240 records. I have searched the site for an answer and I am already using tag_sents in hope that it will boost the performance by reducing the initiation overhead, but still it takes too long. Could you please help me? This is my test code for this one

```
import nltk
from mongo_connect import *

jar = 'E:\\Anaconda3\\stanford-postagger-2017-06-09\\stanfordpostagger.jar'
     model = 'E:\\Anaconda3\\edu\stanford\\nlp\\models\\pos-tagger\\english-caseless-left3words-distsim.tagger'

st = nltk.StanfordPOSTagger( model, jar, encoding='utf-8')

def entity_tagging():
    #data is the collection in MongoDB
    for dat in data.find():
        tex = st.tag_sents(word_tokenize(word) for word in sent_tokenize(dat['title']))
        print(tex)
```

Thank you,in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As you must know if you really looked through this site, the way to get help with your code is to post your code in your question (a relevant but complete snippet, to be exact). Full instructions in the Help section.

Comment: @alexis yes you are right, i've added the code

Comment: You're missing a lot; there's no way to tell what the data type of `data` is, for example? If you're sure that the tagger is the bottleneck, demonstrate the problem by tagging one of the nltk's built-in corpora.

Comment: I've used nltk.pos_tag and nltk.post_tag_sents, and it finished within some seconds, so i assume that the issue is on the tagger

Comment: Unless you provide code that _only_ exercises the bottleneck, you're coming here with a mix of technologies and it's less likely someone will want to dive in and sort them out for you. Also, what is "too long"? Be specific. (PS. Tried a profiler yet?)

Comment: Thanks for giving me some hints, as to where to look at. I havent precicely timed it , but it takes 10+ mins to tag the whole collection. The data type of data is string. Lastly, yes i tried a built-in corpora and it worked fine, so i guess mixing MongoDB and Stanford POS-tagger is the issue, while i'm not quite sure why, because it works with nltk's pos tagger. In any case, thank you for everything, i'll come back,once I have a solution.

Comment: It could be that `data.find()` is blowing out your memory (or enough so that the Stanford tagger no longer fits, and is swapping like crazy.) I don't use MongoDB, but make sure you're not loading the whole corpus in memory before you start processing. Also if the individual documents are large, that `print(tex)` could take forever just to add brackets to the printout; skip it.